# In AC/DC adapters, why can't the DC cable be detached from the adapter?

Tags: connector, cables, adapter, ac-dc

I notice that in most (all?) AC/DC adapters, the DC cable can't be detached from the adapter. Is there a reason for that?

Example:

[image]

**Note: The question is not opinion-based, since the existing answers and comments show there exist some objective answers to the question.**

Comment: They can be...if you're willing to pay more.

Comment: @DKNguyen why more expensive?

Comment: Connectors aren't free.

Comment: @DKNguyen why do they make the AC side dettachable then?

Comment: Because people loose them. Then they might connect the wrong one and blow up the device with the wrong voltage - wife did that to an external drive… 20v instead of 5v. Oops.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt Different countries use different outlets.

Comment: @DKNguyen Got it, thanks, sounds like a nice answer, you're welcome to post it as an answer. I thought there would be some other reason.

Comment: @SolarMike thanks,  sounds like another nice answer, you're welcome to post it as an answer.

Comment: Virtually all cell phone chargers have removable USB cables.  They're certainly AC/DC adapters, and in the case of higher ones that do USB PPS, you can even set the output voltage over a fairly wide range.

Comment: @user1850479 good point, that's interesting that the AC/DC adapters with a USB output are indeed detachable, unlike most non-USB adapters. Any idea why?

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt because usb is designed to meet standards while DC equipment is powered by the design voltage 5v, 12v, 19v  or more as chosen by the designer or manufacturer to keep their costs down.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt You need to provide a USB cable anyways to connect to the computer. So again, cheaper.

Comment: same reason as the ac.  different devices use different connectors - once upon a time mini, micro, B, and quite a few others were common... as were phone chargers that had no detachable parts.  standardization is a curious thing.  IEC for semi-standardizing ~110-230VAC input.   USB A female for 5VDC base output...

Comment: I suspect there's also a very practical reason. Do you trust average consumers not to mix all loose cables they have lying around not to mix them up? No way. And there's no standardized polarization or current capacity of these.

Comment: I still see plenty of cable built in usb chargers. They are not all usb A or C female.

Comment: No clue why the question was closed as opinion-based, since the existing answers and comments show there exist some objective answers to the question.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt This question could be considered as opinion based because to an electrical engineer, it is a matter of opinion. If the question wasn't closed for this reason, it could be closed for other reasons as we typically don't answer questions about consumer devices and not about designing a power brick.

Comment: @VoltageSpike Thanks, the EE answer to "In AC/DC adapters, why can't the DC cable be detached from the adapter?" is "Yes it can", therefore there is an objective  + on-topic answer to it. The main motivation of this question was to know whether it was just a design choice.

Comment: @user1850479 _"Virtually all cell phone chargers have removable USB cables"_ -  here's one reason this question is 'opinion based'. My new Samsung Galaxy A01 charger has a fixed cable, as did my previous phones. Samsung sold 277 million smartphones in 2020, so 'virtually all' is definitely not true.

Comment: @BruceAbbott how is that an opinion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Summary: Cost, reliability, convenience and certification of the assembly with the device.

USB-C Power Delivery seeks to overcome these issues while offering a demountable cable.

**Cost**

An additional connector adds cost. That said, the arguably most common power adapter type on the planet - USB - has a detachable supply-side connector. USB is mature and highly cost-reduced, and most important, *standardized*, so it can get away with this. Not so for a laptop brick.

Nevertheless, USB-C PD power bricks with detachable cords are a thing now, at least for Macs. They do cost more though.

**Reliability**

The DC side connector has to be rated for high enough current to handle the load. Connectors oxidize, have limited mating cycles and thus can fail over time.  The typical barrel type connector is very rugged and is designed for a large number of mating cycles. On the other hand, an additional supply-side connector is an additional failure point.

It remains to be seen how rugged USB-C PD will be compared to a barrel connector. I consider it kind of fragile.

**Convenience**

It may seem ironic that having an attached DC cable on the laptop brick is convenient, but it is. Experience bears this out: in our household we always seem to be one USB cable short of the one we need, at the moment we need it. The laptop power cables never get waylaid in some drawer or glovebox because they’re part of the brick.

USB-C, if it becomes as universal as USB-A, can completely overcome this issue for laptop-capable power supplies. While you still can find yourself without a cable or an adapter at an inopportune time, at least USB-C solutions are somewhat easier to get than a proprietary laptop cable+brick.

Example: I've already invested in a 12V to USB-C PD car adapter so my better half can use her Mac on the go. On a recent road trip I was able to walk into a Staples and get one (and pay too much for it, because, you know, Staples.) Works great, we'll see how it holds up over time.

**EMI/EMC Certification of the Assembly**

The brick you show has an additional ferrite bead at the device end. This is a hint that the device it's powering had issues with conducted electromagnetic interference (EMI), so the manufacturer had to resort to that ugly add-on fix to suppress it. It could also be to suppress fast-transient spikes coming from the power supply to the device. Or it could be doing both things.

Really, EMI issues should be addressed in the device itself using a common-mode filter, but they chose to do this instead on the attached cord. If the cord were detachable this would defeat the EMI workaround.

Speaking of which... a USB-C PD brick and laptop *must* deal with these issues internally. They have to for interchangeability. This would imply a USB-C PD brick and device would be better-designed for EMI/EMC than a dedicated brick.

**Postscript (2/2/2022)**

My shiny-new Lenovo laptop arrived. It uses a USB-C power cable, that is **permanently attached to its power brick.** At least I can charge the laptop with that Staples gizmo.

So, progress?

Answer (score 12):

Because it would cost more since you now need two more connectors.

The AC side is detachable because different countries use different outlets.

ADDITION BY HEARTH:

> ...and the DC side isn't, because these power supplies are typically intended for use with one specific device or family of devices. Either that, or you design the device to use the right power jack.

ADDITION BY Lorenzo Marcantonio

> Also: a detachable AC cable means you can buy a precertified one, otherwise you'll have to do all the paperwork for the cable you supply.

Comment: ...and the DC side isn't, because these power supplies are typically intended for use with one specific device or family of devices. Either that, or you design the device to use the right power jack.

Comment: Also: a detachable AC cable means you can buy a *precertified* one, otherwise you'll have to do all the paperwork for the cable you supply.